# JUnit-How to write test for a file parsing method?

Tags: java, android, file-io, junit, tdd

I'm new to test development and am trying to break my non-tdd habits.

Most of the functional, testable code in my app has to do with database i/o or file reading/writing.  Android provides some extensions for dealing with the database tests, but I'm lost as to how I can write tests for reading a sample file.

Here's an example from my app: XML import.

The method `parseXML()` reads a file with a fairly simple schema and directly writes its contents to the database.  There are several sub-methods that parse the contents of different nodes (i.e. `parseNote()` or `parseList()`).

Do I have to provide a sample file?  If so how?  How should I even start testing code like this?

**Edit**
Sample File:

```
<lists>
<list title="Sample List">
<note title="Note 1" details="Details 1"/>
<note title="Note 2" details="Details 2"/>
<note title="Note 3" details="Details 3"/>
</list>
</lists>
```

Comment: a sample file would be handy.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to unit test the part that saves the information to the database because doing so would require that you have a database up and running.  With unit tests, you want to avoid these kinds of dependencies like the plague.

Instead, what you should do is test the unmarshalling process--that is, does your code correctly extract the data from the XML document.  Create a class whose sole purpose is to hold the parsed XML data (a POJO/bean class with just properties and getters/setters).  Have your `parseXML()` method throw all the data into this class and return it (it shouldn't be saving anything to the database).  Then, all your unit test has to do is check to make sure the object's properties have the correct values.

Like @Woot4Moo said, you should also test how the method handles unexpected errors, like a non-existant file or a non-XML file.

Also, if your XML adheres to a schema, you might want to check out JAX-B.  This is a framework that will automatically create a Java bean object from an XML document, given that the XML document adheres to a schema.  You don't have to write any parsing code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The things you will want to test are as follows:

1. Properly formed XML file
2. Malformed XML file
3. XML file that is > 2GB
4. XML file that does not exist
5. XML file saved as txt file (this really only shows that you aren't relying on the extension)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but is there a specific way I'm supposed to add a test file to the JUnit suite?

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile To make the method more flexible and more easily unit testable, parseXML() should accept something more abstract than a `File` object.  If you use a `Reader` object instead, then this allows you to pass an XML string (`StringReader`) or an XML file (`FileReader`) to the method.  Being able to pass a string into the method makes writing your unit test a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would mock out the database and test that the parser interacts with it correctly when fed snippets of XML.  Or, if you are not familiar with mocking frameworks, you can parse the XML into an intermediate 'value' class (all final fields) and perform equality assertions.

You can create these snippets using a XML builder class.  For basic parsing and building of XML files, using a preexisting DOM library will be much easier than writing one yourself.